# Can anyone suggest what technology and 3D printing material is most suitable for printing of dental models?

Tags: print-material, medical

I'm looking for a 3D printer for applications in the dental field, for printing digital dental models (not for itra-oral use parts).

Resolution and finish are the main requirements that we consider necessary.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I strongly recommend against anything that's not approved by the equivalent of the  FDA in your country.

Comment: If it's only used for printing models, and not anything that will be inserted orally, I don't see a problem. But I think the answer would be rather subjective.

Comment: Hi, Electivo, and welcome to 3D printing SE! In it's current form, any answer to your question will *primarily be based on opinion*, since different users have different experience with various brands and printers. This is something that we try to avoid on SE. However, asking  "what printer *technology* (or perhaps *material*) should I use for dental implants" allows for more objective answers. I have put your question *on hold* for now, so that you can make changes to your question. When ready, please vote for your question to be reopened.

Comment: It still sounds like a proper answer to your edited question would be a specific model of 3D printer - again, this is something we try to avoid. Try to imagine what a good answer to your question would look like - it should an *objective* answer. Take a look [here](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/asking) for more info. Also, adding details to your question could help. Do you have a model example? What options have you already considered, and why are they not sufficient?

Comment: I disagree, reading my question is very clear to me that I am not referring to a specific product, but to a technology and material (the same technology and the same print media are used by hundreds of printer manufacturers to around the world). If you, as moderator, considers "inadequate", then I suggest you remove it from the system. Grateful.

Comment: @TormodHaugene I think we should un-hold this question. The OP is asking for available 3D printer types, such as SLS is a typical technology for medical-grade parts. I can elaborate in an answer once we un-hold it.

Comment: Electivo and @tbm0115, we are currently debating these kind of questions over at the [meta site](http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/185/are-software-recommendation-questions-allowed-here), we would be very interested in hearing your opinions. It is a difficult type of question to moderate, so we are trying to find a common solution on how to respond. I am sorry for the inconvenience. The question has been reopened.

Comment: Hello Tormod Haugene,

Glad to know that my question was re-evaluated and found to be valid. It is very important to us, we can rely on the use of this as a valuable tool.

Often, we have to resort to the aid of translators might write our questions, and this ends up making them confusing for those who are reading.

Again, I would like to thank and congratulate the quality of work.

Comment: It sounds like any material would do the job since you are only making a model, which I guess has no features that are difficult to print. As for the technology, either you print models to scale and get an accurate enough printer, or you get any printer and print enlarged models. I'm not sure an accurate answer can be given here.

Answer (score 3):

If resolution is your upmost concern then resin 3d printers are the way to go. They use a liquid resin that does not harden until a UV laser is shined through them. Apparently they get ultra high resolution and smooth finishes right out of the box. The downside is they are generally more expensive machines and the resin material itself is also a higher cost. but if you are in the dental field then money is not a problem. Look into resin 3d printers.

otherwise if you want to try FDM printers then try looking into .1mm brass nozzles which will increase resolution but vastly increase print time. Not sure what material would be best. ABS has toxic smelling fumes, but is the same as LEGOS and is able to be easily smoothed (if necessary) with Acetone fumes. PLA might work well at .1mm nozzle resolution though and is a starch/dextrin based non-toxic biodegradable filament.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by Andrew, resins should do the trick : most commons processes are SLA and DLP (DLP is faster but more expensive).

- If you aren't looking for precisions (or looking for low budget), FDM
  machines should do the trick.
- If you need metal, I think Solidscape or micro SLM should both work.

You should specify what are your exigences, it's not the same to do an ultra-high precision metal part and to have a $300 maximum-budget machine.